# How to get files from <input type='file' …/> in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to get image file in input field but I could not do it. Here is the code:

```
:on-change (fn [_]
             (this-as this
               (println "Files: " (.-files this))))
```

But `(.-files this)` returns **nil**.

Any ideas?

P.S: I would like to upload this image to my server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a workable snippet from our project:

```
:on-change
(fn [this]
    (if (not (= "" (-> this .-target .-value)))
        (let [^js/File file (-> this .-target .-files (aget 0))]
          ;; your logic here ...
          ;; now reset the widget to let user upload a new one
          (set! (-> this .-target .-value) ""))))
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Albert's answer (and because my edits were rejected):

Instead of using `goog.object/get` as below (and in his answer with `o/get`):

```
(let [dom  (goog.object/get event "target")
      file (goog.object/getValueByKeys dom #js ["files" 0])]))
```

You can also use regular interop forms in ClojureScript:

```
:on-change (fn [event]
             (let [files (.. event -target -files) ; returns JS Array
                   file  (first files)]
               (do-something-with file)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

you must first get the dom node from somewhere. In React world `this` might not be the dom since they are syntactic events.

```
:on-change (fn [event]
             (let [dom  (goog.object/get event "target")
                   file (goog.object/getValueByKeys dom #js ["files" 0])]))
```

Or using regular interop forms in ClojureScript:

```
:on-change (fn [event]
             (let [files (.. event -target -files) ; returns JS Array
                   file  (first files)]
               (do-something-with file)]))
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: what namespace is "o" alias belong to?

Comment: goog.object. You may also use regular interop forms like (.. event -target -files).

Comment: I find using goog.object give me less headache when I need to do advance compiling. So I keep using goog.object for handling js object as a habit.